# Count with row_number function SQL CTE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below CTEs that work perfectly, but I want to count the "cl.memb_dim_id" by "cl.post_date" but I am not sure how to do that? When adding in the count function I get an error that highlights the ' row number' so I am assuming I cant have both order and group together ????

```
WITH 

DATES AS 
(
select to_date('01-jan-2017') as startdate,to_date('02-jan-2017') as enddate


from dual

),

Claims as (select distinct 
cl.memb_dim_id,
row_number () over (partition by cl.Claim_number order by cl.post_date desc) as uniquerow,
cl.Claim_number,
cl.post_date,
ct.claim_type,
ap.claim_status_desc, 
dc.company_desc,
dff.io_flag_desc,
pr.product_desc,
cl.prov_dim_id,
cl.prov_type_dim_id


from dw.fact_claim cl

inner join dates d
 on 1=1

and cl.post_date >= d.startdate
and cl.post_date <= d.enddate 
and cl.provider_par_dim_id in ('2')
and cl.processing_status_dim_id = '1'
and cl.company_dim_id in ('581','585','586','589','590','591','588','592','594','601','602','603','606','596','598','597','579','599','578','577','573','574','576','575')


left join dw.DIM_CLAIM_STATUS ap
on cl.claim_status_dim_id = ap.claim_status_dim_id

left join dw.dim_claim_type ct 
on cl.claim_type_dim_id = ct.claim_type_dim_id 
and cl.claim_type_dim_id in ('1','2','6','7')

left join dw.DIM_COMPANY dc
on cl.company_dim_id = dc.company_dim_id

left join dw.DIM_IO_FLAG dff
on cl.io_flag_dim_id = dff.io_flag_dim_id

left join dw.dim_product pr
on cl.product_dim_id = pr.product_dim_id

)


Select * from claims where uniquerow ='1'
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

First, does this work?

```
count(cl.memb_dim_id) over (partition by cl.Claim_number, cl.post_date) as cnt,
```

Second, it is strange to be using analytic functions with `select distinct`.

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it a try but I am curious on why its strange? sorry still learning and I am always up to see if I am doing something wrong . Im still new with SQL. I thought by using the distinct it gives a unique line, I know I put the row number to dedup but I thought with putting distinct it would help it .

Comment: `select distinct` often indicates an issue with `join`s.  It should not be used, unless you really need the removal of duplicates, because it is relatively expensive.  I would want to get the rows correct in a result set before applying window functions because these are based on the rows in the set.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I will put that in my notes and thank you again I did try the above and it worked perfectly.